# AJAX Bootstrap Modal Not Showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show the following modal, where the body is database driven. However this data isnt appearing in the Bootstrap modal. I've been looking at this for far too long and cant see the issue!

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="eventDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Event Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="dash">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#eventDetailsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modal = $(this);
      var dataString = recipient;

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET", 
            url: "/getNearestPC.php", 
            data: {"foo": dataString}, 
            cache: false, 
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                console.log(dataString); 
                console.log(recipient); 
                $('.dash').html(data); 
            }, 
            error: function(err) { 
                console.log(err); 
            } 
        });  
})
```

**getNearest.php**

```
    //SQL Setup
    $PC = $_GET['foo']; 

<div class="modal-body center" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <table id="preusertable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-curved" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="color: #000000;">Event</th>
                <th style="color: #000000;">Postcode</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        <?php
            while ($row = $sData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $school = $row['SchoolURL'];
                $postcodeFull = $row['Postcode'];
                ?>
                <tr>                    
                    <td style="font-size: 1.1em;"><?php echo $school ?></td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1.1em;"><?php echo $postcodeFull ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Modal Trigger**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eventDetailsModal" data-whatever="<?php echo $postcode ?>">
```

Any help would be great! It just show the modal header but no body

Comment: note: There are no errors in the console

Comment: What does your console.log(data); output after your AJAX call? Probably nothing, right?

Comment: @Y.Hermes Indeed, there is nothing

Comment: Your probleme is your "php code". I'll rewrite it fast for you and post it as a possible answere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of populating it on modal shown event, try doing this on click event of the `<a>`:

```js
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
  var button = $(this); // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $("#eventDetailsModal");
  var dataString = recipient;

  $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/getNearestPC.php", 
    data: {"foo": dataString}, 
    cache: false, 
    success: function (data) { 
      console.log(data); 
      console.log(dataString); 
      console.log(recipient); 
      $('.dash').html(data); 
    }, 
    error: function(err) { 
      console.log(err); 
    } 
  });  
})
```

Comment: Does the same thing sadly, just shows the modal header and not the body which is the AJAX part. Thanks though!

Comment: @Frog82 Wait, you said no errors in console right. What does your Network tab show for return value from PHP?

Comment: @Frog82 The same way you looked at the console. There should be another thing called network. Before you click on the button, clear everything. Then click on the button to see any AJAX calls being fired.

Comment: Nothing going through the network from what I can see

Comment: @Frog82 Aha... AJAX isn't firing then. Is the event getting attached? Try `console.log()` on click?

Answer (score 0):

Save this as your "modal_template.html" :

```
<div class="modal-body center" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
<table id="preusertable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-curved" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="color: #000000;">Event</th>
            <th style="color: #000000;">Postcode</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        {TBODY}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this should be your AJAX request:

```
        <?php
        $PC = $_GET['foo']; 
        $tmpl = file_get_contents("modal_template.html");
        $replace = "";
        while ($row = $sData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $school = $row['SchoolURL'];
            $postcodeFull = $row['Postcode'];
            $replace .=  '<tr><td style="font-size: 1.1em;">' . $school . '</td><td style="font-size: 1.1em;">' . $postcodeFull . '</td></tr>';
        }
        $tmpl = str_replace("{TBODY}", $replace, $tmpl);
        echo $tmpl;
    ?>
```

With that you'll get a clear Template for your modal. If you've posted all of your code, this should help you, and your console.log(data) should log your "modal-template".

EDIT:

Also a little modified your Jquery (Found some missing ";"):

```
$('#YOUR MODAL TRIGGER ID').on('click', function (event) {
event.preventDefault;
var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
var modal = $(this);
var dataString = recipient;

$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/getNearestPC.php", 
    data: {"foo": dataString}, 
    cache: false
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data != ""){
            console.log(data); 
            console.log(dataString); 
            console.log(recipient); 
            $('.dash').html(data);
            $('#eventDetailsModal').modal("toggle");
        }
        else{
        console.log("error");
        }
    }); 
});
```

EDIT: The reason why only your modal header is shown is because `<?php echo $postcodeFull ?>` is finishing your AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
  var button = $(this); // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $("#eventDetailsModal");
  var dataString = recipient;

  $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/getNearestPC.php", 
    data: {"foo": dataString}, 
    cache: false, 
    success: function (data) { 
      console.log(data); 
      console.log(dataString); 
      console.log(recipient); 
      $('.dash').html(data); 
    }, 
    error: function(err) { 
      console.log(err); 
    } 
  });  
})
```